# Why does this print 4 and 12 after executing?

Tags: java

So whenever I run this I get 4 and 12, but I don't understand why that is. I do understand that up until the if statement with (y mod x == 1) is where the code fails. So why does the output say 4 and 12 once this portion fails? Just looking for a nice explanation on why this is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 10, y = 0;
    while (x > 5)
    {
        y = 3;
        while (y < x)
        {
            y *= 2;
            if (y % x == 1)
                y += x;
        }
        x -= 3;
    }
    System.out.println(x + " " + y);
}
```

Comment: Have you executed this step by step using your debugger, inspecting the values of the variables at each step? That would be a good way to find out.

Comment: You can also use paper and pen. Show us where you are stuck, what values you came up with and how.

Comment: An old fashion debugging style was also add a println for each step printing intermediate results.

Comment: @JBNizet I wasn't even aware of the debugger. Any quick tutorial as to how to use it? Thanks

Comment: Try googling "[name of your IDE/editor] debugger tutorial".

Comment: @Kicker714 If you don't know how to use the debugger, you can just `System.out.println` to print the values of variables at key points to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good idea to look through the code step by step:

```
int x = 10, y = 0;
```

So these are your starting values.

```
while(x > 5)
```

Since 10 is bigger than 5, this while-loop will run.

```
y = 3
```

Now y becomes 3, so x is still 10 and y is 3.

```
while(y < x)
```

This while-loop will run because 3 is less than 10.

```
y *= 2
```

So that's y = 3 * 2 = 6, so now x is 10 and y is 6.

```
if(y % x == 1)
```

This is **NOT** the case, because 6 % 10 equals 6. Now the second while loop `while(y < x)` will continue (because 6 is still less than 10), so y becomes 12. But, because the if-statement is still incorrect this while loop will end (because 12 isn't less than 10). Thus, as a part of the first while loop you will have to substract 3 of x, so x becomes 10 - 3 = 7.

Then, you go back to the first while loop to see if x is still bigger than 5. This is the case, because x = 7 and 7 > 5, so the first while loop will run again. Now, y becomes 3 again and the second while-loop will run because 3 < 7. Then y becomes 6 and the if-statement is incorrect again so that won't run. Now we check the second while-loop again: is 6 < 7? Yes, so y becomes 6 * 2 = 12. Again, the if-statement will fail to run. Is 12 < 7? No, so the second while loop will end and as a part of the first while loop you have to substract 3 from x, so x = 7 - 3 = 4.

Final result: x = 4 and y = 12.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a table like this:

```
LOC | x | y
------------
    |   |
```

Now mentally review each line of code and write in the value of both variables. Continue step by step, including all repetitions of the while loop. (LOC stands for "Line of Code". This should be the number of the line of code for each step.) If you mentally execute the code correctly, you will see what the final output is. If you do not get the expected results by doing this exercise, edit your question to show us your manual table and we can help from there.